# Retrieving email from Facebook GraphObject

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am not able to retrieve the email from the Graph Object. I see on my app that I have permission for it. Here is my current code:

```
    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxx','xx');
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('xxx');
    $session = null;
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        Core::session('FacebookAuthSession')->sessionObject = $session;
    } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {

    } catch(\Exception $ex) {

    }
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Comment: where do you see that you have the permission for it?

Comment: @luschn On the developers app page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to execute:

```
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

if($session) {

  try {

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo "Email: " . $user_profile->getEmail();

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
```

To test results, you can also use explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: This did not work. There is no email in my graphobject.

Comment: Did you check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer ? All the information for user will be stored in object there.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are just listed as "approved without review" in your App settings, but you still have to authorize a user with them by using the "scope" parameter in the login process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/